# Rewrite URL prefix into HTTP header

Tags: ruby, url-rewriting, rack

I'm trying to rewrite URLs as follows using `rack-rewrite`:

`/group1/feed` becomes `/feed`, with header `"GROUP_NAME" => "group1"`

Currently, I'm using a hacked version of [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) which allows me to do the following:

```
use Rack::Rewrite do
  rewrite /\/([^\/]*)\/(.+)/, '/$2',
  headers: lambda { |base, route| { 'GROUP_NAME' => base } }
end
```

Note that `base, route` are not provided to the `headers` block in the stock version of `rack-rewrite`.

I'm wondering if there's a less hacky way to accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do you have access to the $1 variable? Also, I'd suggest `%r{/([^/]*)/(.+)}` as it's a lot clearer without the escapes, YMMV.

Comment: The `$1` variable is only available in the 2nd parameter (`/$2`). My "hack" allows it to be accessed (as `base`) inside the headers block.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the source, where `rewrite` is defined](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/v1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite/rule.rb#L22)

```
def rewrite(*args)
  add_rule :rewrite, *args
end
```

you can see it takes a splat of args. [Following it to see the definition for `add_rule`](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/v1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite/rule.rb#L94)

```
def add_rule(method, from, to, options = {}) #:nodoc:
  @rules << Rule.new(method.to_sym, from, to, options)
end
```

one of those splatted arguments is an options hash used to build a `Rule` instance. One of those options is `:headers`, which gets [added to a variable called `additional_headers`](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/v1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite/rule.rb#L119). This is then [merged into the headers in some rules](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/v1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite/rule.rb#L129).

Unfortunately, [`rewrite` is one of the few rules that it ***doesn't*** get merged in](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite/blob/v1.3.3/lib/rack/rewrite/rule.rb#L137). This means that the answer to your question is partly "no", because the current public API won't help you with this. Personally, I can't see any reason for the decision not to merge the options with this rule, and if I were you I'd fork the library and add it, then send a pull request to have them add it to the main branch. While you're waiting, you'll be still be able to do:

```
rewrite /\/([^\/]*)\/(.+)/, '/$2', :headers => {"GROUP_NAME" => $1}
```

from your own fork.